# Which way is the best to implement axios interceptor in react boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, axios, react-boilerplate

I am using react boilerplate which used the fetch library. But now i wanted to implement interceptor, is anyone knows how to implement it using fetch library or should i use axios for that.

Comment: hi you found any good workflow ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very simple task, for example add a './interceptor.js' file like below:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.interceptors.response.use( (response) => {
   return response;
}, (error) => {
   switch (error.response.status) {
        case 400:
             console.log('Bad request');
             break;
        ...
        default:
            ....
   }
return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

then import this file to 'index.js':

```
import './interceptor.js';
```